# How to prepare my code for Azure Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, webpack, azure-functions

I have some project on ES6. For exaple with one file:

```
export default function (a, b)
   {
    return a+b;
   }
```

I'm transform it using webpack and babel to one file with ES2015 code. And get something like this:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "/";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    module.exports = __webpack_require__(1);


/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    "use strict";

    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
      value: true
    });

    exports.default = function (a, b) {
      // return aCalc(a) + bCalc(b);
      return a + b;
    };

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

Now I want use my function in Azure Function. For this I create file calc.js and fill it with webpack output and try to call it from my main function:

```
var calc = require('./calc');

module.exports = function (context, req) {
var result = calc(2);
context.done(null, result);
};
```

and get error

Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerJS1. mscorlib: TypeError: calc is not a function
    at module.exports (D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTriggerJS1\index.js:11:30)
    at D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.10690\bin\Content\Script\functions.js:83:24.

And now Questin: how I should prepare my code for call it in Azure Function?

Comment: why are you using webpack ? azure function executes server side javascript.

Comment: You can improve your cold start time by consolidating your server-side code into a single file, minimized. Most server-side developers don't think too much about this since their servers are long lived, but in a serverless world where load time of files can impact cold start of less active functions from ms to seconds, it's worth considering in certain cases.

Comment: @Thomas, I cannot run ES6 code on Azure Function, so I need to transpile it, I f it will be smaller in result - thats good too.

Comment: @Chris Anderson-MSFT maybe you know any ready solution for transpile and minificate code?

Comment: We had someone use browserify and just loaded everything onto the global object, which isn't something I'd recommend as a best practice, but it does work. Webpack is the next thing I'll probably investigate, but I don't have a good answer right now. Hoping to just solve the issue by providing an alternative to Azure Files for consumption plan in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you do not need to transform your code to ES5, because the code run in Azure Functions is Node.js Javascript in server side not front-end Javascript. And the latest Node.js supports most of the ES6 (ES2015) syntax and features.

> The website [node.green](http://node.green/) provides an excellent overview over
>   supported ECMAScript features in various versions of Node.js, based on
>   kangax's compat-table.

So please consider upgrading version of Node/NPM to higher instead. To do this see below.

1. Go to the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/) in your browser.
2. Navigate to your Function App and click **Function app settings**.
3. Click **Configure app settings** button, then set `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `7.2.0`.
   [image]
4. After that done, you check that in dev console.
   [image]

> You can see all node version supported by Azure at the URL `https://<yourappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/diagnostics/runtime` of Node WebApp.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thats great, documentation say "The node version is currently locked at 6.5.0." and doesn't tthink, that I can change this parameter. But I still need code preparation:
1. for strip flow annotations
2. for fix my import path: I use something like "import { convertor } from 'Convertors/ConvertorA';" with webpack option "resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    root: [ path.resolve('./src'),  path.resolve('./node_modules')]
  },"

Comment: Maybe you can tell me how to fix this probles without process my file with webpack? I already find right configuration for this, but, maybe, deploing my code without any changes will be better.

Comment: Change path to relative, still get same error:
import { convertor } from '../Convertors/ConvertorA';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
Maybe you can explain what wrong with it?

Comment: Unfortunately `WEBSITE_DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION` is not used by azure functions because it depends on edgejs to run node scripts, which uses version 6.5.0.

Comment: Matt Mason is right, this information is misleading. You can set the version but it has no effect on what node version Azure functions use

Answer (score 2):

For most web apps Aaron is correct, `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` will set the version of node that your application will run.

Unfortunately azure functions does not run node in the same way and is locked at 6.5.0 due to a dependency on edgejs.

One of the github issues has a good [comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/298#issuecomment-273851188) on how they enabled bundling for azure functions. In your specific case, I think that you will need to include a `require` of your function in the bundle itself, instead of simply exporting the function:

`global.deps = { calc: require('./calc') };`

Then, to use the bundle in your function:

```
// require your bundle
require('<nameofyourbundle>');

// dependencies are stored in the global object under 'deps'
var calc = global.deps.calc;

// your exported function
module.exports = (context, req) => {
  context.done(null, calc(2));
}
```